# How to add up a string of numbers using SQL (BigQuery)?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a string of numbers like this:

```
670000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I want to add up these numbers which in the above example would result in 14: `6+7+0+...+1+0+...+0+0+0=14`

How would I do this in BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
with example as (
  select '670000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' as s
)
select s, (select sum(cast(num as int64)) from unnest(split(s,'')) num) result
from example
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yet another [fun] option

```
create temp function sum_digits(expression string)
returns int64
language js as """
  return eval(expression);
""";
with example as (
  select '670000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' as s
)
select s, sum_digits(regexp_replace(replace(s, '0', ''), r'(\d)', r'+\1')) result
from example
```

with output

[image]

What it does is -

- first it transform initial long string into shorter one - `671`.
- then it transforms it into expression - `+6+7+1`
- and finally pass it to javascript `eval` function *(unfortunatelly BigQuery does not have [hopefully yet] `eval` function)*